# How to add a link to a particular word in a sentence?

Tags: jquery

I have to create a link after the user enters his statement in the text box.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? This seems like a question about HTML.

Comment: I can able to create hyper link for the whole sentence.my requirement is to create link only to a particular word.

Answer (score 1):

How would you create a normal hyperlink?

`<a href="...">Hai</a>, How are you`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `jQuery` tag is correct and you want DOM-manipulation, here's an answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/APUHd/

```
<button>Link words</button>
<div id="sentence">Hai, How are you</div>​
```

```
var jqSentence = $('div#sentence');
var aSentence  = jqSentence.html().split(' ');

function LinkWord(iIndex, sHref) {
    aSentence[iIndex] = '<a href="' + sHref + '">' + aSentence[iIndex] + '</a>';
    jqSentence.html(aSentence.join(' '));
}

$('button:first').click(function(){
    LinkWord(1, '/some/path');
    LinkWord(3, '/some/other/path');     
});
```

​